# Recorrer carpetas python

Tags: python, archivo

tengo este código:

```
import os
rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Directorio encontrado:' + dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t' + fname)
```

Necesito que se guarden en una variable:
¿Qué tipo de variable (diccionario, listas, etc...) es mejor?
¿Como lo hago?

El resultado que quiero es que me aparezca una lista numerada (la variable que comentaba antes) de todos los archivos.

PD: soy un principiante :)
Muchas gracias

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-get-list-of-files-in-directory-and-sub-directories/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esos datos pueden ser guardados en multitud de tipos iterables, pero como parece que se trata de un ejercicio, y ya que has mencionado los diccionarios y las listas, se podrían combinar ambos. Se podría crear un diccionario que como clave tuviera el nombre del directorio y como valor una lista con los nombres de los archivos.

En caso de no conocer el funcionamiento de las listas y los diccionarios, antes de seguir, lo recomendable sería que echaras un vistazo a la documentación para que te informaras.

- [Más info diccionarios](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dictionary#dict)
- [Más info Listas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dictionary#list)

Por ejemplo, sin dar muchas vueltas a tu código, podría quedar:

```
import os
rootDir = '.'
result = {}  # Declaramos el diccionario

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    filenames = []  # Declaramos la lista en la que se almacenarán los nombres de archivo.
    for fname in fileList:
        filenames.append(fname)  # Añadimos el nombre de archivo a la lista
    result[dirName] = filenames  # y por último seteamos el diccionario (como clave está el directorio y como valor los archivos.
```

Ahora que todo está almacenado en `result`, podemos imprimirlo de la misma forma que en tu ejemplo:

```
for dir, fileList in result.items():
    print('Directorio encontrado:' + dir)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t' + fname)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Saludos te dejare un pequeña guia:

```
import os


path = 'contenedora'
directorios = []
for dir in os.listdir(path):
    element= {}
    element['directorio'] = dir
    path_nuevo = path +'/'+str(dir)+'/'
    for file in os.listdir(path_nuevo):
     element['archivo'] = file
     directorios.append(element)
print directorios
```

Mi estructura de directorios:

```
- test
  - contenedora
      - prueba
        -prueba.txt
      -prueba2
       -prueba2.txt
  test.py
```

lo que hace primero es obtener el listado de las carpetas mediante el listdir, esto le agrego a un array element, posteriomente armo un nuevo path que sera con el path principal + la nueva carpeta hallada y mediate un ciclo for recorro su contenido y lo agrego al array , al final imprimo todo quedando algo asi:

```
[{'directorio': 'prueba', 'archivo': 'prueba.txt'}, {'directorio': 'prueba2', 'archivo': 'prueba2.txt'}]
```

ya solo es cuestion de ir validando si es folder o file e ir agregando en el array o como gustes.

espero te sirva y guie.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)